# How to generate signature and keys in Codeigniter RSA library

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, rsa

I am doing some encryption and decryption in php using codeigniter framework. I am using this library https://github.com/Dirktheman/rsa-codeigniter-library. What I want to do is I generate a signature like this `encrypt_method(value,private_key)`.

That will return signature. Then I want to verify the value that is equal to out previous value or not decrypt(signature,previous_input,public_key). What my problem is there is no method to generate private and public key. For generating signature as well. So, how can I achieve it using RSA library in PHP?

Comment: The Rsa class has a `generate_keys` function, but it is [hilariously insecure](https://github.com/Dirktheman/rsa-codeigniter-library/blob/master/application/libaries/Rsa.php#L33-L87) ("randomly" selecting 2 four-digit primes). This is basically obfuscation and should not be used. Just use phpseclib if you want RSA functionality in PHP.

Comment: Be sure to note that the HackerHunter RSA implementation from 2002 it was based on is also insecure for the same reasons.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Do not use that library. It is completely insecure.

A secure RSA implementation depends on the use of randomly generated *large* prime numbers (e.g, at least 2048 bits!) as part of a private key. However, this library does not use large prime numbers, nor does it even generate them randomly — [**it picks them from an array of 570 pregenerated four-digit numbers**](https://github.com/Dirktheman/rsa-codeigniter-library/blob/master/application/libaries/Rsa.php#L38). This means that there are only about 162,000 (570 * 569 ÷ 2) possible keys that could be generated; this is few enough that you could easily generate a list of all possible public and private key pairs.

Additionally, this library is using RSA in an inappropriate mode. It is "encrypting" and "decrypting" messages by encrypting each group of three letters as a separate, independent message. This scheme is insecure, as the individual blocks can be edited and reordered to create new messages. (For instance, an encrypted message that said `SEND JO $123` could easily be edited to say `SEND JO $123123` by repeating the last block!) Worse, if the content of one message is known, it is possible to search for blocks from that first message within another message to recover parts of its contents.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. To stress it further, anyone with a minimal understanding of how RSA works could break messages encrypted with that lib literally using a piece of paper and a pocket calculator.

Comment: Author of the library mentioned here... I'm sorry! I wrote this a couple of years ago as an excercise. I wouldn't implement it in a live website as it's completely insecure. I'll remove it from GitHub ASAP.

Comment: @DirkdeMan Thanks, although it looks as though a lot of people are already using it. :( https://github.com/search?q=rsa+%2B+%24primes+%3D+array%284507&type=Code

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So is this dead ?

Comment: @duskwuff - Looking at those search results, it's safe to say that the 20 files using a similar primes array probably didn't get it from this library, as they are mostly older. As mentioned by Henk Poley above, patient zero seems to have been Hacker Hunter back in 2002.